# RestKit Mapping error when compiling release builds iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, restkit

I am using RestKit in one of my projects and using it to map a json response. The mapping behaviour as expected on a fresh install or debug build.

However when complied as a release build and distributed via TestFlight all my mapping fails. Logging the JSON to the console shows the json to be as expected and matches the model.

I can only assume recently i have made a compiler change (or xCode defaults have changed) but i cannot spot what is causing the issue.

Anyone had this issue before?

Cheers

Dan

Update: i have tried updating to latest stable build of Restkit and not made a difference

Comment: Have you checked the header search paths under each configuration (though I would expect build issues if that were the problem)? How does the mapping fail?

Comment: I would assume this would cause a build failure. URL.... which failed to match all (0) response descriptors. Error: rg.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 \"No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched.

Comment: This is the first time you've run a release build? What in your code is dependent upon the DEBUG definition?

Comment: First install is alway ok. It seem to be when you go over the original. Or at least version 1 had no issue. Compiler flag -DDEV_BUILD for both. Release also includes -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1

Comment: So you start with a clean device, install once - OK, install the same app again - not OK?

Comment: Correct. Only happens on release builds, either through Jenkins or Testflight

Comment: Only idea at the moment is to add some logging to your code where you setup the mappings and check it's running as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted the project settings to default and slowly added each item until it started to work. I think I had a missing DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTION.

Hope this helps someone in the future